# Can the JPA executeUpdate lock a row indefinitely?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

This is related to [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38127641/how-to-use-jpa-lock?noredirect=1#comment63698722_38127641)

I've implemented a PESSIMISTIC_WRITE lock in my application to avoid data problems on Concurrent procedures.

The problem is even with this and the INNODB_LOCK_WAIT_TIMEOUT variable set to 120 I'm still having deadlocks.

I'm checking the source (I'm new in this project) and the way we update a row using JPA is different to I'm used to.

We use a typed query to update a row i.e.

```
TypedQuery<Account> q = em.createQuery("UPDATE Account a SET a.balance=a.balance+:quantity",Account.class);
q.setParameter("quantity",100);

q.executeUpdate();
return;
```

What gets my attention is there is not a commit,merge,flush or anything that ensures me I'm closing the transaction like the merge method from the EntityManager.

Comment: are you using transactions - I hope so.

Comment: sadly I don't see any transaction annotation in the method that updates the row. I repeat this is not my code I'm used to use the EntityManager methods such persist,merge,refresh, etc.

Comment: An executeUpdate call will result in an exception if executed outside a transaction.  So the call must be being made within a transaction. Pessmistic locking is usually done on reads, so you can know upfront and wait for other locks to complete before proceeding with your locks.  If you are getting a deadlock, you'll have to see  the rows you have locked and the rows the other process has locked, and rearrange the order they obtain those locks.  You need way more information then this one method.

Comment: Also, a timeout value isn't going to prevent deadlocks, only reduce the amount of time you keep your locks for.  Only ensuring the order you get the locks is consistent among all the many possible processes that may need to pick one up will 'prevent' deadlock.  This is why it is usually recommended to use optimistic locking, and just retry the transaction in the event of a conflict.

Comment: Thanks @Chris , but is not optimistic locking used when you don't expect a collision ? , I mean when you ARE sure a read will not happen while you are updating? , In this case I'm sure a read will occur while I'm updating , even an update could occur from other server while I'm updating the same row. That's why I used pessimistic lock which  do a "select .... for update"

Answer (score 0):

The auto-generate DAO code that I use in Eclipse projects shows javadocs such as

```
 * <pre>
 * EntityManagerHelper.beginTransaction();
 * NodesDAO.save(entity);
 * EntityManagerHelper.commit();
 * </pre>
```

Using this as a hint (and maybe look at your other code), try

```
TypedQuery<Account> q = em.createQuery("UPDATE Account a SET a.balance=a.balance+:quantity",Account.class);
q.setParameter("quantity",100);

em.getTransaction().beginTransaction();
q.executeUpdate();
em.getTransaction().commit ();
```

BTW, you should not have to mess about with `PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` and `INNODB_LOCK_WAIT_TIMEOUT`

Comment: This is due to a concurrent update of the same row ... I need to lock it  to avoid lose of data